# How to use different colors for each line in pygame.draw.lines

Tags: python, pygame

I recently started to learn `pygame` and herein lies my question. Is there anyway I can use different colors for each line drawn using `pygame.draw.lines`? This is my code.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480), pygame.SCALED)
screen.fill('white')

pygame.draw.lines(screen, 'red', True, [(10, 100), (20, 200), (30, 100)]) # all lines are red

while True:
    pygame.display.update()
```

Output I get

[image: Output I get]

Output I want

[image: Output I want]

What I tried

```
 pygame.draw.lines(screen, ['green', 'blue', 'orange'], True, [(10, 100), (20, 200), (30, 100)])
```

Error

```
ValueError: invalid color argument
```

In other words, I want to achieve what I want in the following code but using `pygame.draw.lines`

```
pygame.draw.line(screen, 'green', (10, 100), (20, 200))
pygame.draw.line(screen, 'blue', (20, 200), (30, 100))
pygame.draw.line(screen, 'orange', (30, 100), (10, 100))
```

I checked the `pygame.draw.lines` [docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.lines) but I am not sure if the `color` argument there takes a list as I have given. It only mentions "`Color or int or tuple(int, int, int, [int]))`"

This example is for a triangle, but in my actual use-case I want to draw a decagon and I am not sure if using `pygame.draw.line` 10 times is the way to go if I want a different color for each line.

PS : Do let me know if any clarification is needed. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to draw each line segment separately. Write a function that uses a list of points and colors to draw the line:

```py
def draw_colorful_line(surf, colors, closed, points, width=1):
    for i in range(len(points)-1):
        pygame.draw.line(surf, colors[i], points[i], points[i+1], width)
    if closed:
        pygame.draw.line(surf, colors[-1], points[-1], points[0], width)
```

Use the function to draw the line:

```py
colors = ['green', 'blue', 'red']
points = [(10, 100), (20, 200), (30, 100)]
draw_colorful_line(screen, colors, True, points)
```

[image]